# Why i get double or triple messages sent when i write script for one time send, discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Why isn't my code going into debug 4 zone? I think it may be the discord server's fault, if you have any answers please share.

```py
globals()['i'] = 0

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    time.sleep(3)
    apple_channel = bot.get_channel(829849505775091742)
    print('debug 1')
    if str(message.author) == "Hyetabot11#2254" or globals()['i'] == 0:
        print('debug 2')
        while globals()['i'] < 12:
            print('debug 3')
            await apple_channel.send(i)
            print('debug 4')
            globals()['i'] += 11
            print('debug 5')
            break
```

result:

```
debug 1
debug 2
debug 3
debug 1
debug 2
debug 3
debug 1
debug 2
debug 3
debug 4
debug 5
```

in this example I get two times sent messages, when I code it to only once.

Also, how did it go from `debug 3` to `debug 1` ?

****SOLUTION**:**

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
```

Comment: What are these `debug` outputs signifying?

Comment: its just for testing

Comment: Your code isn't the most readable. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Clearly you received another message while you were waiting for yours to be sent.

Comment: Why do you use the `globals()['i']` hack instead of `i=0`, `global i`, and `i += 11`?

Comment: i can't use `i = 0` in `on_message` discord event. `global i` too. Because it get stuck on zero every message sent in chat

Comment: I tested it on my local discord guild, bot doesn't receive any new message while do this code

Comment: You don't need to edit your question with the answer, just mark the answer that helped as accepted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that the bot may be responding to it's own messages! To fix that, you should add this to the top of your `on_message()` function:

```py
if message.author == bot.user:
        return
```

This will check if the `author` of the `message` (`message.author`) is the `bot` (`bot.user`). If so, it will just ignore the message (`return`). Otherwise, it will continue to execute the code from within the function.